# @typescript-eslint/naming-convention - How to use to enforce consistent `catch` variable names?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

This seems to be possible with https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/rules/catch-error-name.js but I didn't want to re-implement this if @typescript-eslint could theoretically support it, but I'm not quite sure how to implement this to only handle `catch` blocks.

For example I would like:

```js
try {
...
}
catch (ex) { // should always be called "error"

}
```

to fail since it doesn't match "error" as the required catch name.

How can I implement this using https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/naming-convention/ ?